# How does the AES CBC algorithm check if a password turned key is correct?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm using [this class](https://github.com/feresg/java-steganography/blob/master/src/Steganography/Logic/AESEncryption.java) to encrypt a file or a byte array using the AES/CBC algorithm.

However, I don't understand how this algorithm is implemented in Java to check if a password turned key is correct or not. When entering a wrong password, a `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException` is thrown. Here's the error message:

> Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

Does this algorithm store the key inside the encrypted document? What exactly is an Initialization Vector and how does Java proceed to check if a given password turned key is true or not? What happens exactly during the decryption process?

Comment: Please don't use SHA1 for deriving keys from password .. instead use a propper key derivation functions designed for this like PBKDF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code specifies that you use a PKCS5 Padding (with `CIPHER_SPEC = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`). This means that 1 - 16 bytes are padded at the end of your clear data before encrypting. This padding ensures that the data aligns to the block size of AES (16 bytes) before encrypting. The padding is constructed in such a way that it's easy to detect that it's the padding (the number of bytes padded is what is padded .. eg. if 5 bytes is needed, the padding is `05 05 05 05 05`).

If you decrypt with the wrong key you end up with random data, that most of the time would also give you an invalid padding. As the padding is invalid, the cipher don't know where the data ends and give you a `BadPaddingException`.

Comment: I just need a bit of clarification, does decrypting a file with a wrong password/key end up with a file with a size that isn't a multiple of 16 bytes and why?

Comment: If the last decrypt call you make, don't see decrypted data with a correct padding it will fail (and not give you any data that might remain) .. if there happens to be something that is a valid padding (can happen by chance), the padding will be removed, and you would be handed the rest of the data without this padding. You should not rely on this mecanism to validate that a correct password have been entered .. consider using an authenticated mode like GCM to catch integrity errors like this.